# Periodicity and fundamental frequency detection algorithms

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have some time series datasets which are periodic, and I'd like to pick out the fundamental frequency of the data and take the average over a fundamental period.

Questions:

1) Would something simple like taking the FFT of the time series data and looking for the strongest peak frequency do the trick, or are there more complicated period detection algorithms out there? For what it's worth, I'm trying to do all this in MATLAB.

2) There are some edge effects, particularly at the beginning of each data set. Would I have to take this into account?

Comment: "taking the FFT of the time series data and looking for the strongest peak frequency do the trick"  Nope.  the strongest peak could be different from the fundamental.  In fact, the fundamental might not even be there.  https://gist.github.com/255291

Comment: Can you put up a plot of the type of periodic signals you are looking to get periodicity out of?

Comment: @endolith Curious - how can a periodic signal not necessarily have a fundamental?

Comment: @endolith: The strongest peak frequency won't be the fundamental in my data sets - this is an annoyance that I have to work around.

Comment: @Mohammad: imagine a signal of the form $\sum_{1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\sin(2 \pi n t)$

Comment: @Mohammad : Periodic with no fundamental?  Easy, take any periodic signal with strong harmonics and subtract the fundamental with a bandpass filter.  Deep male voices sent though an old telco circuit are almost *exactly* like this.

Comment: In this blog, I show how to create a low frequency pitch (or lowest periodicity) using only high frequency tone bursts: http://www.musingpaw.com/2012/04/musical-pitch-is-not-just-fft-frequency.html

Comment: @Mohammad: The overall periodicity is the GCD of the frequency components.  If you have a wave made up of 200 Hz and 300 Hz, it will repeat at 100 Hz even though there's no 100 Hz component.

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the problem of [Pitch Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm).  A fairly simple approach is to compute the autocorrelation (FFTs can be used to do this quickly),  and look for the peak with T > T_min

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: I've ended up using a Lomb-Scargle MATLAB script.

Answer (score 1):

The strongest peak of an FFT is only good at periodicity estimation if you can absolutely guarantee that the fundamental frequency has more power than any overtone or harmonic.  This is not true for many types of phenomena that are periodic.  But if it is true, then windowing can help reduce edge effects.

However, an FFT can be used as part of a more sophisticated periodicity or pitch detection/estimation method, such autocorrelation by fast convolution, or a cepstrum, or a harmonic product spectrum.  etc.